# Plotting a data.frame from within a function with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have this function to take an object returned by the IRT package sirt and plot item response functions for a set of items that the user can specify:

```
plotRaschIRF <- function(x,items=NULL,thl=-5,thu=5,thi=.01,D=1.7) {
  if (!class(x)=="rasch.mml") stop("Object must be of class rasch.mml")
  thetas <- seq(thl,thu,thi)
  N <- length(thetas)
  n <- length(x$item$b)
  tmp <- data.frame(item=rep(1:n,each=N),theta=rep(thetas,times=n),b=rep(x$item$b,each=N))
  probs <- exp(D*(tmp[,2]-tmp[,3]))/(1+exp(D*(tmp[,2]-tmp[,3])))
  dat <- data.frame(item=rep(1:n,each=N),theta=rep(thetas,times=n),b=rep(x$item$b,each=N),p=probs)
  #dat$item <- factor(dat$item,levels=1:n,labels=paste0("Item",1:n))
  if (is.null(items)) {
    m <- min(10,n)
    items <- 1:m
    if (10<n) warning("By default, this function will plot only the first 10 items")
  }
  if (length(items)==1) {
    title="Item Response Function"
  } else {
    title="Item Response Functions"
  }
  dat2 <- subset(dat,eval(quote(eval(item,dat) %in% items)))
  dat2$item <- factor(dat2$item,levels=unique(dat2$item),labels=paste0("Item",unique(dat2$item)))
  out <- ggplot(dat2,aes(x=theta,y=p,group=item)) +
   geom_line(aes(color=dat2$item),lwd=1) + guides(col=guide_legend(title="Items")) +
   theme_bw() + ggtitle(title) + xlab(expression(theta)) +
   ylab("Probability") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(thl,thu,1))
  print(out)
}
```

But it seems to be getting stuck at either the line just before I start using ggplot2 (where I convert one column of dat2 to a factor) or at the ggplotting itself -- not really sure which. I get the error message `"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dat2' not found".`

I tried reading through [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) but either this is a different problem or I'm just not getting it. The function works fine when I step through it line by line. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this line: `subset(dat,eval(quote(eval(item,dat) %in% items)))` really just trying to select the rows of `dat` where the values of the column `item` are in the vector `items`?

Comment: Save yourself the heartache and don't use `subset` inside a function.  It's meant for interactive use.  Why don't you `dat2 <- dat[dat$item %in% items, ]`

Comment: yes that's all it's meant to do, and I actually originally had what @BrodieG suggests, but I originally thought the error message was due to this line and went on a whole eval spree to try to fix it before realizing it wasn't that (or, at least, subsequent lines still led to the same error message). I don't think the problem is here -- the function will get past this line before crashing (I can have it print stuff in between that terrible line and the next line).

Comment: It might be better to use the `fortify` approach that`ggplot2` implements for `lm` objects. Once you have written a fortify.raschmml method that creates data frame, which you can then call `ggplot` more easily

Comment: I hadn't heard of `fortify`, thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the error is almost certainly in `geom_line(aes(color=dat2$item))`.  Get rid of `dat2$` and it should work fine (i.e. `geom_line(aes(color=item))`).  Stuff in `aes` is evaluated in the `data` argument (`dat2` here), with the global environment as the enclosure.  Notably this means stuff in the function environment is not available for use by `aes` unless it is part of the `data` (`dat2` here).  Since `dat2` doesn't exist inside `dat2`, and `dat2` doesn't exist in the global environment, you get that error.

Comment: ...and for goodness sakes get rid of that `subset(eval(quote(eval()))` nonsense! :)

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much, I didn't even suspect the geom_line bit (when stepping through the function it didn't work unless I had dat2$item there). And yes @joran that terrible line is gone (I didn't want it there to begin with!)